# spring data jpa: Not an managed type: class xxx

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, repository

I am having issue with spring data jpa. I have cloned this repository https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth and it was working totally fine. Then I wanted to replace import.sql with real database and I wanted to connect it with postgres.
I followed next tutorial: http://devcrumb.com/hibernate/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-maven

It recognized my database but there is some runtime error:

```
    10:41:00.281 [hello.Application.main()] WARN     o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class hello.model.Role
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jpaData" />
</persistence>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">

<!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="hello.data" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/locoDB</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>postgres</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>postgres</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here is entire project: https://github.com/criticalbh/spring-oauth-postgres

Comment: You cannot just replace SQL files directly with DB, you have to configure it too. Please post your configuration.

Comment: Please edit your main post, and add the entire configuration there. Remove the comment.

Answer (score 4):

The `Not a managed type` error usually indicates that the persistence unit does not 'know' about your Entity class.

In the `persistence.xml` you should list the Entity classes that you want Hibernate to 'manage' like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="jpaData">
    <class>your.package.here.YourEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

at the end I end up with

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "hello.data"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PersistenceContext {

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
   // HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/locoDB");
    dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    dataSource.setPassword("postgres");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource   dataSource,
                                                            Environment  env) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean =  new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new   HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("hello.data");

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to  create SQL
    //that is optimized for the used database.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",  "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");

    //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
    //SessionFactory is created or closed.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            "update"
    );

    //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
    //new database objects and schema elements
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
           "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"
    );

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
    //statements to the console.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
            "true"
    );

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
    //that is written to the console.
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
        "true"
    );

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

Application class:
    `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(PersistenceContext.class);`